# java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java

Given a, b and c, return true if any one of them can be formed by a mathematical operation using the other two numbers. the mathematical operations permitted are addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. For e.g `if a=12, b = 15, c = 3 output is true (15-12 = 3).`
i tried solving the problem, though the solution works most of the time but it does not work in case of `'0,0,255'` or ohers similar to this. 
My code :-

```
public class CheckCombination {

    static int testcase11 = 0;
    static int testcase12 = 0;
    static int testcase13 = 512;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        CheckCombination testInstance = new CheckCombination();
        boolean result = testInstance.combine(testcase11,testcase12,testcase13);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    //write your code here
    public boolean combine(int a, int b,int c){
        boolean checkComb1 = a==(b/c)||a==(b+c)||a==(b-c)||a==(b*c)||a==(c-b)||a==(c/b);
        boolean checkComb2 = b==(a/c)||b==(a+c)||b==(a-c)||b==(c*a)||b==(c-a)||b==(a+c);
        boolean checkComb3 = c==(a/b)||c==(b/a)||c==(a-b)||c==(b-a)||c==(a*b)||c==(a+b);
        boolean finalCheck = checkComb1||checkComb2||checkComb3;
return finalCheck;
}}
```

what am I doing wrong and what can changes can possibly correct this problem or I am just thinking wrong?

Comment: `NullPointerException` is not an `error`.

Comment: Where do you get the NPE?

Comment: There is no NPE ! There is a java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Comment: I don't see where you can get the NPE.

Comment: If you google you'll notice that this site is 99% people posting about their NPE's/various exceptions. Learn how to debug. Start by reading the stack trace, which comes with a line number.

Comment: While @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ is correct, that doesn't really help the user :P  please post the stack trace of your exception

Comment: on using cases wherein there are zeros involved. it works for the rest of the problem

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
 at nullpointer.CheckCombination.combine(CheckCombination.java:19)
 at nullpointer.CheckCombination.main(CheckCombination.java:11)

There you go its just a simple divide by zero

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
 at CheckCombination.combine(CheckCombination.java:17)
 at CheckCombination.main(CheckCombination.java:9)

Comment: so how do i correct my program for it to work properly ??

Comment: @user3289229: By checking the divisor, as suggested in the answers below. And for future reference, please be more accurate with the type of error/exception/problem that you're having.

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is that you divide by zero like here: `(a / b)` `a=0 and b= 0`

---

So, you need to check if one of the parameters is 0 so that you can guess the other parameters like:

```
If one of the parameters = 0, if the others are equal, return true else return false
If two of the parameters = 0, it will return false and doesn't matter what the last value is
If the all parameters = 0, you will return true
```

Comment: yes and I am relatively new to java or programing for that matter. its a simple assignment question and it is not supposed to produce errors! i know there are better ways to solve this problem but I have done th e best I can without taking any help. so any help on rectifying the above code would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is a division by zero problem and not NPE.

Tip: Before you do division, check your **DIVISOR** first.

Also, you can improve your code by:

```
    public boolean combine(int a, int b, int c) {
        boolean check = checkIfOk(a,b,c);
        check = checkIfOk(b,a,c);
        check = checkIfOk(c,a,b);
        return check;
    }

    public boolean checkIfOk(int a, int b, int c) {
        boolean ret = a==(b+c) || a==(b-c) || a==(b*c);
        if(c != 0) ret = ret || a==(b/c);
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go, just check your divisor using something like this first

> if (testcase11 != 0 && testcase12 != 0 && testcase13 != 0)

Answer (score 0):

check the denominator if it is zero otherwise Divide by 0 Exception occurs.

public class Test {

```
static int testcase11 = 0;
static int testcase12 = 0;
static int testcase13 = 512;

public static void main(String args[]){
    Test testInstance = new Test();
    boolean result = testInstance.combine(testcase11,testcase12,testcase13);
    System.out.println(result);
}

//write your code here
public boolean combine(int a, int b,int c){

    boolean checkComb1 = (c!=0)?a==(b/c):false||a==(b+c)||a==(b-c)||a==(b*c)||a==(c-b)||(b!=0)?a==(c/b):false;
    boolean checkComb2 = (c!=0)?b==(a/c):false||b==(a+c)||b==(a-c)||b==(c*a)||b==(c-a)||b==(a+c);
    boolean checkComb3 = (b!=0)?c==(a/b):false||(a!=0)?c==(b/a):false||c==(a-b)||c==(b-a)||c==(a*b)||c==(a+b);
    boolean finalCheck = checkComb1||checkComb2||checkComb3;
```

return finalCheck;
}}

Comment: thank you so much! cud u help me further by explaining to me what you did?

Comment: Please check your logic. I have just given you an idea how to check the denominator with zero value to avoid the Divide by Zero using ternary operator as you were writing the code in a line.